# Adding a RealmChangeListener to object created with copyToRealmOrUpdate

Tags: android, realm

I have a messaging application which uses **RealmDB** to store messages and threads for users. The message threads are `RealmObjects`. I'm trying to figure out how to add a `RealmChangeListener` which will trigger when any of the threads are **updated** (i.e a new message is received). The threads are initially retrieved and subsequently updated from my `MessageThreadList` activity via a *syncMessages* function in the **API**. It seems like no matter where I try to add the listener I get the

> Cannot add listener from unmanaged object

error.
My code:

### MessageThread.java

```
public class MessageThread extends RealmObject {

    //Some member variables here - Id, title, etc

    //This is the field that would indicate a new message if changed
    private Date mLatestSentTimeStamp;

    //Empty constructor
    public MessageThread() { }


    public MessageThread(JSONObject jsonOb) {
        //Filling fields from JSON here
    }
}
```

### ThreadListActivity.java

```
public class ThreadListActivity {

    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Realm.init();
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        MyAPI.syncMessages();
    }
```

### MyAPI.java

```
static protected void syncMessages() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();

    JSONArray jsonMsgThreads = getJSONFromServer();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMsgThreads.length(); i++) {
        MessageThread m = new MessageThread(jsonMsgThreads.getJSONObject(i));
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(m);
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

If it's not possible to add it anywhere here, is there anything that I could do to have a listener on each MessageThread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ThreadListActivity {

    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults<MessageThread> messageThreads;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
         super.onCreate(bundle);
         Realm.init(this);
         realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
         messageThreads = realm.where(MessageThread.class).findAll();
         messageThreads.addChangeListener((results) -> {
            // any message thread was modified 
         } 
         MyAPI.syncMessages();
    }
```